# accessing a transformed texture's pixel data

Tags: c++, directx

How do i access the TRANSFORMED pixel data for a texture, after it has been transformed (rotated and scaled) by `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D()` and `texture->SetTransform()`?

I'm trying to do 2D pixel perfect collision detection and it's impossible if you can only access the untransformed pixel data using `texture->LockRect()`.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This will not achieve the results you wish. With the `SetTransform` method you set a transformation which is applied before the texture is drawn. So it wont morph your image that you can read out the pixel values.

What you **could** do is to project world coordinates to UV coordinates of your texture and then read out the according pixel value and compare it and do your collision resolution there.
I guess you use the inverse matrix of the matrix you created by `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D()`.